# How to display characters in assembly in DOS?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, dos

I have this following code in which I tried to display but my debugger (AFD) keeps on debugging but doesn't display anything.

```
[org 0x100]
                mov ax, 0xb800
                mov es, ax
                mov di, 0

nextchar:       mov   word [es:di], 0x0720
                add   di, 2
                cmp   di, 40
                jne   nextchar

    mov ax,0x0003  ; 80x25 text mode, 16 colors
    int 0x10
```

Comment: Um, `0x20` is the space character, and you're specifying black as the background color, so I'd say what you see is the expected behavior.

Comment: Besides printing spaces on the top line, It also doesn't help that when you are finished that you set the video mode which will generally clear the screen.

Comment: I changed 0x0720 to 0x0741 but it's still the same

Comment: Prior to running your program clear the screen first with `cls` command at dos prompt. Possible the changes you make to the top line of screen scroll off.You could also put `mov ax,0x0003` `int 0x10` before you write to the display. Setting display mode will generally clear the screen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Give yourself an opportunity to actually **see** what you output by waiting for a keyboard key before exiting:

```
[org 0x100]
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 0
nextchar:
    mov   word [es:di], 0x0741 ; Will show 20x "A"
    add   di, 2
    cmp   di, 40
    jne   nextchar

    mov   ah,0x00
    int   0x16                 ; Wait for a key

    mov ax,0x0003              ; 80x25 text mode, 16 colors
    int 0x10
```

Comment: I'm sorry i have identified my problem it was not other than my own mistake. I wasn't familiar with DOS.